# Using Android App Bundle how do i get the system to download a new language when the system language is changed

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I am migrating my app to use Android App Bundle publishing format.
I'm using Internal app sharing to test this change.

While installing the app for the first time I can see that the app is installed with all the languages I have added to the System languages menu.

incase I add a new System language that wasn't added before the installation of the app, how do I make Android download the new language strings?

As you can see here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0raqVydJmNE&t=789s

It should get downloaded automatically.
But after i add a new language and go into my app the Locale is changed to the new language but my resources are still the language from before the switch.

I know I can use [Core API](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/feature-delivery/on-demand#lang_resources) to download languages in the code but I want the app to startup with the correct language not change language in the middle of the user's usage.

Is there anything I'm missing? do in seed to configure something else in gradle?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can take a little while (usually around 24 hours) for the Play Store to catch up with the language change. If you're okay with that delay, then you don't need to do anything.

Otherwise you can use the [code provided in the official sample](https://github.com/android/app-bundle-samples/blob/main/DynamicFeatures/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/samples/dynamicfeatures/MainActivity.kt#L202) to guide you in your own implementation.